# LibreOfice Impress PPT Animation problem

Tags: 16.04

I am working on LibreOffice Impress to make presentations. But whenever the presentation is copying from Ubuntu to Windows it's changing the format and animations are changes badly. Is there any solutions to solve this problem??

Comment: Are you using LibreOffice on both Windows and Linux? (That is, not Powerpoint or Google Docs or some other viewer?) Are they both (roughly) up to date versions?

Comment: No, I am using LibreOffice Impress in Linux but when it is copy from Linux to other laptop which is with Windows OS the format of presentation is changing.

Comment: Do  you view the presentation on the Windows computer? If so, which software do you use?

Comment: Yes i can view the presentation on windows computer using Microsoft power point.

Comment: Ahh you're using Powerpoint instead of LibreOffice on the Windows computer -- that's what I suspected and why I asked my first question

Comment: Okay...sorry forgot to say that clearly

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Powerpoint and LibreOffice Impress use different transitions and default file formats. Powerpoint likes to change LibreOffice presentations into its own Powerpoint format, which doesn't always work well.

For best compatibility for the presentation between your two computers, I'd advise using LibreOffice Impress on your Windows computer for editing LibreOffice presentations, instead of using Microsoft Powerpoint.

Comment: Thank you.....but my problem is we will work on Linux LibreOffice Impress and the presentations are shared with many school children. Most of the schools use Microsoft power point. We can't suggest them to use LibreOffice Impress in Windows instead of Microsoft power point.

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding. I don't think there is any way to get LibreOffice transitions to work properly in Powerpoint. If you need *exact* copies, one option, (if you're distributing the presentation online) would be to use Google Docs (or similar) to develop the presentation. Then the schoolchildren could view your presentation in Google Docs. Or you could use LibreOffice, but export your presentation a format like PDF that is widely viewable with different software (but you might lose some features like slide transitions)

Comment: Okay fine.......but I saw one software in Ubuntu software center that is PlayOnLinux. By using this can we install Microsoft powerpoint in Ubuntu.

Comment: You can certainly give it a try, though newer versions of Powerpoint might not work. I think Powerpoint 2000, 2003, 2007, and 2013 work best in Playonlinux, but there are no guarantees. If you have a good internet connection, you could use the free version of PowerPoint Online instead: https://office.live.com/start/PowerPoint.aspx